# How to feed data to LSTM cells in TensorFlow for multiclass classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a dataset of one-line sentences and each sentence belongs to a class based on the context. I have created a lexicon of important words and converted my input data into a list of features, where each feature is a vector of the length of the lexicon. 
I want to input this data to a dynamic LSTM cell, but can't figure out how to reshape it.
Consider my batch_size = 100, length_lexicon = 64, nRows_Input = 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `numpy.reshape`?
Check out this documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

For example:
`>>> a = np.arange(6).reshape((3, 2))`
`>>> a`
`array([[0, 1],`
       `[2, 3],`
       `[4, 5]])`

> numpy.reshape¶
>
> numpy.reshape(a, newshape, order='C')
>
> ```
> Gives a new shape to an array without changing its data.
> Parameters:   
>
> a : array_like
>
>     Array to be reshaped.
>
> newshape : int or tuple of ints
>
>     The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length. One
> ```
>
> shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from
>   the length of the array and remaining dimensions.
>
> ```
> order : {‘C’, ‘F’, ‘A’}, optional
>
>     Read the elements of a using this index order, and place the elements into the reshaped array using this index order. ‘C’ means to
> ```
>
> read / write the elements using C-like index order, with the last axis
>   index changing fastest, back to the first axis index changing slowest.
>   ‘F’ means to read / write the elements using Fortran-like index order,
>   with the first index changing fastest, and the last index changing
>   slowest. Note that the ‘C’ and ‘F’ options take no account of the
>   memory layout of the underlying array, and only refer to the order of
>   indexing. ‘A’ means to read / write the elements in Fortran-like index
>   order if a is Fortran contiguous in memory, C-like order otherwise.
>
> ```
> Returns:  
>
> reshaped_array : ndarray
>
>     This will be a new view object if possible; otherwise, it will be a copy. Note there is no guarantee of the memory layout (C- or
> ```
>
> Fortran- contiguous) of the returned array.